# How to append the output of bashrc to txtfile

Tags: bash

In Linux terminal, What is the command string to append the output of bashrc to a text file (ex. mybash.txt) I know that with appending you use the double carrots '>>' but do not know how to append the output of bashrc to the text file.

Comment: Do you mean this?: `cat .bashrc >> mybash.txt`. It's not clear for me.

Comment: do you mean during initialization, put the output of the `.bashrc` to a specific file?

Comment: Thanks alot!!! that worked..if i wanted to tail the last 4 lines of that textfile what would be the command? @j.a.

Comment: `tail -4 infile >> outfile`

Comment: and of course "the output of .bashrc" is different than the contents of .bashrc, so maybe you really want `. bashrc > /tmp/bashrc.out`. Note that solutions using `>>` will keep appending to `outfile` each time the line is executed. When debugging something its very easy to get thrown off by what you see at the top of the file, which maybe months old, when you really need to see what is at the end. Ah, hence your requirement for `tail`. Well not always a good idea, but I can see that you understand that  you're creating a history. Less certain about your need for "output". Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cat file >> outfile`. If you only want to read the start of the file you can use:

```
head -N file >> outfile # where N is the numbers of lines you want to write
```

For the last part of a file you can use:

```
tail -N file >> outfile # where N is the numbers of lines you want to write
```